# Todays date is missing in query result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm having a scenario to fetch some data from a table and display it in date order. it must display only 10 records ie.. 4 days before today's date and 5 days after today's date. 
Every thing is working from below query  but current date is missing from my  result

```
select fr.startDate,sum(fr.completed_visit) as completed_visit,sum(fr.canceled_visit) as canceled_visit,sum(fr.Failed_visit) as Failed_visit,    sum(fr.buyer_visit) as buyer_visit,sum(fr.buyerre_visit) as buyerre_visit,sum(fr.visit_sheduled) as visit_sheduled, sum(fr.visit_conferm) as visit_conferm from (select  start_date as startDate,timecreated ,DATE_FORMAT(timecreated,'%d-%b-%Y') as timeformat,
case when (visit_status='Completed') then 1 else 0 end completed_visit,   
case when (visit_status='Cancelled') then 1 else 0 end canceled_visit,
case when (visit_status='Cancelled/Failed') then 1 else 0 end    Failed_visit,
case when (visit_purpose='BuyerVisit') then 1 else 0 end buyer_visit,
case when (visit_purpose='BuyerReVisit') then 1 else 0 end buyerre_visit,
case when (confirm_status='0') then 1 else 0 end visit_sheduled,
case when (confirm_status='1') then 1 else 0 end visit_conferm 
from mg_visit_listing  order by startDate desc) fr
where  fr.startDate <=CurrentDate+5 group by fr.startDate order by fr.startDate desc  ;
```

I'm not fetching the value which is  more then CurrentDate+5 but my current date is  missing from my result

Comment: may be `Current_Date`?

Comment: currentDate+5 will be '2014-9-10'  if im am taking today's date as current date

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining CurrentDate, or is a var you defined earlier?.

When comparing dates you should use [date_add](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) and [date_diff](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

Also, a more detailed explanation would not hurt (something like the create table and a few inserts for a start).

Comment: currentDate+5 will be '2014-9-10' if im am taking today's date as current date
where i need to use  date_add/date_diff methods ??

please help

Comment: Using date_add and date_diff is a suggestion, not the solution. Like Mikahil suggested it's Current_date, not currentDate